# How do I write directly to video memory without xorg?

Tags: c, video, framebuffer, drm

Kind of an odd question I know, but fifteen years ago I was able to use svgalib on some ancient version of Debian to draw directly to video memory without xorg.

To my dismay I see svgalib was pulled from Debian ten years ago. (understandable of course)

I've heard that other options include DirectFB and fbdev, and possibly DRM? I can't seem to find any information. What would you recommend? I really just want a way to set the video mode and a pointer to video ram and I'm set...

Comment: https://landley.net/kdocs/htmldocs/drm.html

Answer (score 1):

> What would you recommend? I really just want a way to set the video mode and a pointer to video ram and I'm set...

Use the Linux framebuffer (`/dev/fb0`, you need to activate the kernel module).

Basically you just `mmap` it, and the mapped area is your video ram. Use `ioctl` on it to set a video mode.

You can find plenty of examples with googling, e.g. [this one](https://gist.github.com/FredEckert/3425429).

Comment: Thank you! This method isn't deprecated or anything?

Comment: The framebuffer device is used quite frequently for UIs in embedded systems, so I it's definitely not deprecated, and I don't think it will go away ...